# how to install uploadprogress with php 7.0

Tags: php7

I'm happily running  my LAMP stack with php 7.0 except that I require `uploadprogress.so` and attempts to install it with PECL result in compile errors.

What do I need to tell Ubuntu 14.04 to use the correct libraries etc to compile `uploadprogress.so`?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you installed PHP 7.0:

- From `ppa:ondrej/php` - just do `apt-get install php-uploadprogress`
- From sources - you need to build the extension from current git tree:

  ```
  git clone git@git.php.net:/pecl/php/uploadprogress.git
  phpize # just make sure the default phpize belongs to PHP 7.0
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

Answer (score 2):

php-uploadprogress is not available by default on Ubuntu 16.

```
sudo apt-get install php-uploadprogress
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php-uploadprogress is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'php-uploadprogress' has no installation candidate
```

What is the best way of installing so that any updates will be installed in the future?

I found a possible solution...
https://www.drupal.org/node/2718253

You can also try...

With this PPA the installation of the upload progressbar for PHP 7 should work also.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Followed up by this command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then the uploadprogress for PHP7 can be installed via:

```
sudo apt-get install php-uploadprogress
```

Comment: If You find that command `add-apt-repository` doesn't exist then install it with: `$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties`